# What does “Arg = Owned To Guaranteed” mean in Swift crash log?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app running perfectly without any crashes in my phone. But in some other device it get crashed with error log **function signature specialization Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed** 
How to trace the problem. Im using coredata.

Comment: Relevant: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6078